# Numba "LoweringError" for complex numbers in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba, numba-pro

I have to make a calculation using complex arrays, however when using numba to speed up the process I get an error `numba.core.errors.LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)`. Here it is a simplified version of my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from numpy import array

@jit(nopython=True)
def func(x):
   a = 1j
   v = x*array([[1.,a],
                [2.,3.]])
   return v
func_vec = np.vectorize(func)

print(func_vec(10.))
```

It is important to note that if `a` is real, everything works well. I have already tested a `dtype=np.complex128` for `v`, but the issue remain.

Numba version: 0.51.0

Numpy version: 1.22.3

Python version: 3.8.10

System: Ubuntu 20.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code crashes is because of a limitation with numba. Numba seemingly does not like it when you use the numpy `array` function to create an (multidimensional!) array filled with complex values. You can work around the issue as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

inp_arr = np.array([[1, 0],
                    [2, 3j]], dtype =np.complex128)

@nb.njit(nb.complex128[:, ::1](nb.complex128, nb.complex128[:, ::1]))
def func(x, arr):
    v = x*inp_arr
    return v

func_vec = np.vectorize(func)

print(func_vec(10))
```

Alternatively, you can just simply assume the array is compile time constant:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def enclosingFunc(x):
    inp_arr = np.array([[1, 0],
                        [2, 3j]], dtype =np.complex128)

    @nb.njit(nb.complex128[:, ::1](nb.complex128))
    def func(x):
        v = x*inp_arr
        return v

    return func(x)

enclosingFunc = np.vectorize(enclosingFunc)
print(enclosingFunc(10))
```

Note that the numpy `vectorize` function is not made for good perfomance, according to the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.23/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). You could look into using the numba `vectorize` decorater instead, but that is outside the scope of your question.

Interestingly, giving the numba decorater the type hint `locals={'arr':nb.complex128[:,::1]}` did not work as an alternative answer

Comment: Hi @Rafnus, thank you for your answer! I tested your code and it does not work when 2 is a complex number, say `2j`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Marcos I edited my answer, I hope it can help you now

Answer (score 1):

For sure the best and most complete answer was from @Rafnus, but to report another simple work around to someone that face the problem in the future is just addind the null imaginary part to other elements of the array:

```
from numba import jit
from numpy import array, vectorize

@jit(nopython=True)
def func(x):
    a = 0+1j
    v = array([[1+0j,a],
               [2+0j,3+0j]])
    return x*v
func_vec = vectorize(func)

print(func_vec(10))
```